# Conditional assignment using while

Tags: c++, optimization

I've been studying some code (in order to extend it) and I came across this segment:

```
// 'assignList' is an unsigned int array: "unsigned int assignList[ numElements ]"
// 'postAssignList' is a std::vector< unsigned int >
for ( unsigned int pp; pp < numElements; ++pp )
{
    while( assignList[pp] != postAssignList[ assignList[pp] ] )
    {
        assignList[pp] = postAssignList[ assignList[pp] ];
    }
}
```

I don't understand why a `while` loop is being used for a conditional assignment. Is this an optimization technique? Or does it ensure the assignment (which I thought is guaranteed)?

Comment: It _looks_ like an optimization technique, so you're not assigning a value if `assignList[pp]` already holds that value. I'm not sure if the technique is worthwhile, though, since you're just using a conditional and possibly an assignment instead of a straight-up assignment. It's also odd to see this as a `while` loop; generally this sort of optimization shows up as an `if`. Personally I would shy away from something like this, although it's possible someone more experienced would disagree.

Comment: @computerfreaker: Wouldn't a plain `if` do the job? I would think `while`s have more overhead.
@harold: No, this code was heavily peer reviewed. Although possible, highly unlikely.

Comment: assignList[pp] could change, so assigning value could be different on the subsequent iteration.

Comment: I believe the assembly for an `if` and a `while` look almost identical aside from an extra goto at the end.

Comment: This is a genuine, non-trivial algorithm that performs some index permutation - the loop does exactly what it says it does.

Comment: @Kerrek SB i'm not, it was a typo and i wanted to fix the spelling, if the change is not appropriate it can be changed.

Comment: Okay, so as far as I understand, it does exactly what an `if` does, nothing more (nothing less). @Joachim: I doubt I'll see any changes in the object code, the code is huge :P

Comment: By the way, a conditional assignment such as `if (a != b) a= b;` would be completely unproductive compared to a straight assignment `a= b;`. The test is more costly than the assignment, and it spares the assignment in just a fraction of the cases.

Comment: @Raxvan: Got it, that's fine - let's change it to just "don't", though, I think that's nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not at all a conditional assignment, this is a plain iteration. Changing the value of `assignList[pp]` causes in turn a change of `postAssignList[ assignList[pp]]`. This looks like a list traversal.

```
while( x != Next[ x ] )
{
    x = Next[ x ];
}
```

Before you execute the `for` loop, every `assignList[pp]` points to a linked list terminated by a self-loop.

After execution, every `assignList[pp]` points to the tail element of the initial list.

Comment: But the whole thing is inside a `for` loop. So for a particular value of `pp` the values of `assignList[pp]`, `postAssignList[ assignList[pp] ]` would be 'constant'. So why would I need a `while` loop for condition checking? (Or am I being blind and missing something obvious?)

Comment: Yes, you are blind. It does not matter that `pp` stays constant, `assignList[pp]` does change. Let `assignList[9] == 0`, `postAssignList[0] == 1`, `postAssignList[1] == 2` and `postAssignList[2] == 2`.`assignList[9]` will be assigned values `1` then `2`.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Sadly, it took some hand holding to get there :( Thanks a lot, Yves!